# Can't display blank table cells in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I've got the following code which shows my clubs fixtures/results list for upcoming games:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <span  id="hide" class="first">1st XV Fixtures/Results</span><span id="show">2nd XV Fixtures/Results</span>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <tr>

                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Venue</th>
                <th>Opposition</th>
                <th>Kick Off</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Score</th>
                <th>Result</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach ($fixtures as $fix)
                @if($fix['team'] === 1)
                    <tr class="clickableRow success league_table" href="{{ action('DynamicPages@match',[$fix['id']]) }}">

                        <td>{{ date("d/m/Y",strtotime($fix['mdate'])) }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $fix['venue'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $fix['opposition'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ date("H:i",strtotime($fix['mdate'])) }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $fix['type'] }}</td>
                        @foreach($results as $result)
                            @if($result['match_id']=== $fix['id'])
                                @if(!empty($result['score']))
                                    <td>{{ $result['score'] }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $result['result'] }}</td>
                                @else
                                    <td> </td>
                                    <td> </td>
                                @endif
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </tr>
                @else
                    <tr class="clickableRow danger merit-table" style="display:none;" href="{{ action('DynamicPages@match',[$fix['id']]) }}">

                        <td>{{ date("d/m/Y",strtotime($fix['mdate'])) }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $fix['venue'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $fix['opposition'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ date("H:i",strtotime($fix['mdate'])) }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $fix['type'] }}</td>
                        @foreach($results as $result)
                            @if($result['match_id']=== $fix['id'])
                                @if(isset($result['score']))
                                    <td>{{ $result['score'] }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $result['result'] }}</td>
                                @else
                                    <td> </td>
                                    <td> </td>
                                @endif
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </tr>
                @endif

            @endforeach

        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want it to show the score from the DB, but if thats blank, then just to show a blank table with a background colour. However, it's simple showing nothing so when I look at it, it shows a white space.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What happens if you add
`table {
  empty-cells: show;
}` to your css?

Comment: The html when viewed doesn't even show an empty cell there!

Comment: Maybe you could provide a jsfiddle with css that you are using and set an example when this occures.

Comment: the css is really only bootstrap, the only thing that is unique is the JS which switches between showing league fixtures and merit fixtures, which hides/shows whole divs, so wouldn't be interfering.

Comment: @danjswade How can you have a table when your `@foreach` doesn't even run duo to `$fixtures` size being zero?

Comment: you have a style="display:none;" in your table

Comment: @hmtareque that is part of the show/hide JS I mentioned earlier. Two tables, one hidden, one showing. Button to switch between the two

Comment: @CrackingTheCode not sure what you mean? $fixtures is a list of fixtures for a team, which is populated from the controller and brought into the view. I then loop through each fixture to display that particular fixture in a row.

Comment: can put example data and controller code plz. may be controller is not printing the view.

Comment: @danjswade What I mean is for an empty table, that array will be have size of zero.

Comment: @CrackingTheCode $fixtures is populated with all the fixtures for the forthcoming season, so will always have data. And in any case, I'm saying if $result['score'] is empty, then display a blank cell with a " " in it, that way I'll get a coloured background

Comment: @hmtareque here is a gist with the controller  code https://gist.github.com/danjswade/82c307a913df8cb561d0. The data will be:

Fixtures: general information (opposition, kick off time etc)
Results: id will match with Fixtures and contain the score, result (win/lose/draw) and who scored

Comment: @danjswade Have you tried this: `@else
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                @endif`

Comment: @CrackingTheCode yep, tried that. I've also tried entering a string too, just to get it to print something.

I think I'm just going to have to go right back to the beginning and check all my code. Something is broken along the way